# Kotlin Data class copy extension

Tags: kotlin, immutability, data-class

I am trying to find a solution for a nice kotlin data class solution. I have already this:

```
data class Object(
    var classMember: Boolean,
    var otherClassMember: Boolean,
    var example: Int = 0) {

    fun set(block: Object.() -> kotlin.Unit): Object {
        val copiedObject = this.copy()
        copiedObject.apply {
            block()
        }
        return copiedObject
    }

    fun touch(block: Object.() -> kotlin.Unit): Object {
        return this.set {
            classMember = true
            otherClassMember = false
            block() }
    }

}

val test = Object(true,true,1)
val changedTest = test.touch { example = 2 }
```

the result of this method is that the `changedTest` object has `classMember = true`, `otherClassMember = false` and `example = 2`

The problem with this solution is, the class properties are not immutable with `var` declaration. Does somebody have an idea how to optimize my methods to change `var` to `val`?

Comment: why don't you just use: `someObj.copy( classMember = true, otherClassMember = false )` (assuming something like: `val someObj = Object(....);`)?

Comment: Kotlin's `copy` method for data classes doesn't copy an object as is and change it's state afterwards. Object construction is the last step of the method. Just decompile Kotlin bytecode and you'll see that here is no way to perform such an optimization.

Comment: @Roland Because I want to use a method which always change two values of two properties additionally to what the user wants to change...

Comment: I updated my question with a complete example...

Answer (score 1):

`val` says that a variable can't change it's value after initialization at the definition point. Kotlin's generated `copy` method does not modify an existing copy after construction: this method actually uses retrieved values from an object, replaces these values with ones that provided in `copy` method (if any), and after that **just constructs a new object using these values**.

So, it is not possible to perform such an optimization if you are going to change object's state after construction.

Comment: ... except... you are willing to use reflection... with reflection near everything becomes possible... (this should also be seen as disclaimer that you **shouldn't** supply such a function that uses reflection to fill up the values, when there are already the overloaded `copy`-functions...)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want correctly, you can do

```
data class Object(
    val classMember: Boolean,
    val otherClassMember: Boolean,
    val example: Int = 0) {

    fun touch(example: Int = this.example): Object {
        return copy(
            classMember = true,
            otherClassMember = false,
            example = example)
    }

}

val test = Object(true,true,1)
val changedTest = test.touch(example = 2)
```

Though you need to repeat parameters other than `classMember` and `otherClassMember` but without reflection you can't do better.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible but I want to have it more generic. I want to have the possibility to change every class member, but I do not want to have all of those as parameter in the touch method. How would a solution with reflection look like?